# How many groups are there on a fixed set with $n$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I remember reading an exercise about how many groups there are on a given set with $3$ elements; in the exercise, it was made clear that this is *not* about the number of groups of order $3$, up to isomorphism. Although there is only one group of order $3$, up to isomorphism, given a three-element set $\{a,b,c\}$, there are three ways to impose a group structure on $\{a,b,c\}$, since we can choose $a$, $b$, or $c$ to be the identity, and once we have made such a choice, the multiplication table is uniquely determined.

This made me wonder about the following question: let $S$ be a fixed set with $n\in\mathbb N$ elements. How does the number of group structures that can be imposed on $S$ relate to the number of groups of order $n$, up to isomorphism? I know that there isn't an "explicit" formula for the number of groups of order $n$, up to isomorphism, but I wonder if there could still be a formula linking these two functions together.

Comment: There are other duplicates on this site (and elsewhere) but they all say pretty much the same thing, namely that very little is known, outside of some special cases based on the factorization of $n$.

Comment: @lulu: It seems to me that that question is considering how many groups there are of a given order, up to isomorphism. However, I'm asking a slightly different question: given a set with a fixed number of elements, how many group structures can be imposed on it? For instance, there is only one group of order $2$, up to isomorphism, but given a two-element set, we can impose a group structure on it in two different ways because either of the two elements can be chosen as the identity.

Comment: It won't be easier to classify, or count,  all the groups together with all possible isomorphisms.