How many of the 16 different results of a binary operations $*$ on a set of $2$ elements give a group structure?
I know this is quite an introductory problem, and I also met it in the first few chapters of the abstract algebra textbook I'm using at the moment. However, the reason I'm asking is that my answer is different from the answer at the back of the book, and I still haven't figured out why.
Firstly, the answer I got was 1 and the following process is how I got it:
To begin, we know that in a group there must be an identity element, and so for a binary operation $*$ on a set of two elements, the table for the binary operation must have the top row and the left-most column arranged in this manner:



*
e
a




e




a





where $e$ is the identity element and $a$ is the remaining element in the set. But as $e$ is the identity element, we have that $e * e = e, e * a = a$ and $a * e = a$, so the table above should be further filled as:



*
e
a




e
e
a


a
a




For the single remaining entry, we know that because the set $\{e, a\}$ form a group under $*$, $a$ must have an inverse (i.e. there must exist $a' \in \{e, a\}$ such that $a * a' = a' * a = e$), and so the last entry can only be $e$.
And that is how I got $1$ as the answer.
However, the answer at the back of my textbook says $2$ ? I'm a little confused. Is there something wrong about the way I approached this problem?  Or is it simply that the answer provided is wrong?
Many thanks for any reply from someone more experienced in group theory.
Moreover, concerning an interesting extension of this problem, I wonder what would be the way to calculate the number of group structures formed among the multiple ways a binary operation $*$ could be applied on a set of $n$ elements. I know that by filling the table there are $n ^ {n ^ 2}$ number of results for $*$, but I have no idea about how to find a formula for the number of group structures among these $n ^ {n ^ 2}$ results.
Update: There turns out to be some duplicates of this extension problem that have been previously answered by others. For instance, at this site. So no need to answer that in this post now.

Both elements of the set can be an identity element.

As @Matsmir says. But you have solved the (different but) more interesting question, when one is allowed to permute the rows/columns.

@Matsmir Oh yeah, why have I not noticed it... But thanks for the response, I the problem with my approach now.

@ancientmathematician yeah, i guess so :-). Though I still think the extension question on the generalisation of the problem is interesting. Hope someone could answer it.

duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4653184/1107685

@Zoe Allen Oh, thanks! Haven't been able to find it myself.

Your thinking is almost right. Consider Boolean Algebra : We have group with XOR & with XNOR , which are the two ways the text book wants.

@Prem Yeah, I see what you mean.

XOR has Identity 0 + XNOR has Identity 1 : those are two ways

True. The group isomorphism ideas are useful.

You have correctly identified that there is a single group with two elements up to isomorphism. However, that is not what the question is asking for. There was one choice that you made right at the beginning, at that is choosing one of the two elements to be the identity element. You could have chosen the other one. After that, as you correctly argue, there are no further choices. Hence there are two possible group operations on the set $\{a,b\}$, the one where $a$ is the identity and the one where $b$ is the identity.
